# Topology "flowchart" or "inclusion tree"

Tags: general-topology

Has anyone come across a good topology flowchart/inclusion tree with embedded counterexamples for proper inclusions? I remember seeing such an inclusion chart for algebraic structures at one point but am wondering if there is a similar good reference in topology.

By inclusion tree, I mean a chart that outlines from general to specific different types of topologies ordered by inclusion, e.g. Hausdorff includes metric.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom has a section 'Relationships between the axioms' with a messy flowchart containing some of what you're asking for.

Comment: Maybe not exactly the format you're looking for, but here's something that might still give you the information you're looking for: https://topology.jdabbs.com/

Comment: Have a look at „Counterexamples in topology“ by Seebach & Steen. It features several dependency charts and counter examples.